# Typeahead request blocked: Time: 30035

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Everytime I run Android Studio it comes with error "Typeahead request blocked: Time: 30035" . The number is always between the range 30000.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this by restarting Android Studio.